# How to pass a customized system message to langchain csv agent?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am using csv agent by langchain and AzureOpenAI to interact with csv file. I want to pass a customized system message to the model. How should I do it? Here is my code:

```
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
     deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
     #model_kwargs={"deployment_name": "gpt4"},
     model_name="gpt-3.5",
     temperature=0.0,
    
 )



python_agent = create_csv_agent(
                            llm,
                            './device_data.csv',
                            #tool=PythonREPLTool(),
                            verbose=True,
                            agent_executor_kwargs={"handle_parsing_errors": True},
                             agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
                      )
```

agent.run(query)

I am expecting to pass system message such as instruction , data frame description that is suitable for all query to the model without repeat this part in the query